# iOS Sliding Drawer

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, amslidemenu

I am using [`AMSlideMenu` in my project](https://github.com/SocialObjects-Software/AMSlideMenu) for sliding view. Where in storyboard,  `AMSlideMenuRightTableViewController` is use to draw some static cell. But I want to add some customized view here, like user profile image, user email, setting icon etc like in the Facebook or the Gmail app. Can any one help me, how should I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Add the views in `AMSlideMenuRightTableViewController` in the `UIStoryboard`.